# Horizon returns 404 when trying to query accounts/{ID}/payments

Tags: horizon, payments, docker

I've spun up a Stellar horizon server using the Docker image mentioned in the repo below

https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon

It spins up just fine but I don't get any payment history. ie. this URL returns a 404

https://myserver.com/accounts/GCOSW43SJO3V3M3B7APU6OEVB3CY2L4INUUWTNHDNLGOSNVF3JHRSMLB/payments

while it works fine for

https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GCOSW43SJO3V3M3B7APU6OEVB3CY2L4INUUWTNHDNLGOSNVF3JHRSMLB/payments

Removing `payments` makes it work and I get account info just fine

https://myserver.com/accounts/GCOSW43SJO3V3M3B7APU6OEVB3CY2L4INUUWTNHDNLGOSNVF3JHRSMLB

The only issue i see other having is

[Horizon server returning 404 for GET /accounts/{id}/payments](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/657/horizon-server-returning-404-for-get-accounts-id-payments)

which mentions that INJEST needed to be enabled, but it looks like it already is default true in the docker. Other queries run just fine such as ledgers/ and accounts/

Any advice?

Comment: Are your horizon and core synced? How did you check?

Comment: I checked by querying horizon for the most recent ledger and the ledger number matches what I see from horizon.stellar.org. Is there a better way?

Comment: The correct answer is below. You need to run `horizon db backfill`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem but it seems I figured it out. If you want the full history available on your horizon you need to do the following.

Run your stellar-core with `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true`. On your horizon side you need to manually tell it to ingest historical ledgers. Just starting horizon with `--ingest=true` is not enough as it will only ingest ledgers that stellar-core currently processes. The steps to manually ingest history are as follows.

1. `horizon db init` initialized db schema
2. `horizon db backfill NUM_LEDGERS` set this slightly higher than the current ledger on stellar-core. This way it should back fill all the way to the beginning of history.
3. `horizon --ingest=true` Start your horizon with ingest=true to keep it up to date. Horizon can run while you are doing the db backfill in the background.

Maybe there is easier/better ways to do it but this is what worked for me. The docs all just mention --ingest=true but you really also need to do the db backfill for full/more complete history.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the specific payments that you see in the public horizon instance are older than your oldest ingested ledger. By default, the docker image's stellar-core configuration will only fetch recent history.

You can verify this by fetching horizon's root element and checking the `history_elder_ledger` field. In https://horizon.stellar.org/ it's `1`. In your own horizon this will probably be newer.

Stellar's core sample config contains some useful information: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg#L220

Horizon's admin overview can also help: https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/admin.md#correcting-gaps-in-historical-data

Comment: I don't see anything in the config file to ingest the entire ledger. What do I change?

Comment: I tried setting HISTORY_RETENTION_COUNT="10000000" (about 3 years)

Comment: And CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true. Now the server seems to resync over and over. I see this type of line 

```2018-09-26T16:55:55.573 GCWVK [History INFO] Catching up: applying checkpoint 70318/315168 (22%)
2018-09-26T16:55:55.913 GCWVK [History INFO] Catching up: applying checkpoint 70319/315168 (22%)
2018-09-26T16:55:56.241 GCWVK [History INFO] Catching up: applying checkpoint 70320/315168 (22%)``` 

cross my screen all the time and it cycles from 0-100% and back to 0%

Comment: `HISTORY_RETENTION_COUNT` is a horizon setting that limits retention on the horizon side. You need stellar-core to do a full catchup so that horizon has the entire history to ingest in the first place. `CATCHUP_COMPLETE` is indeed the setting you're looking for. It takes ~2-7 days, depending on your hardware, to perform a full catchup. If you have specific errors with that I'd recommend opening another question with information and logs

Comment: Is there an estimate amount of diskspace needed to run a full history server? I had a 160gb machine as I saw posts here that the Core only needed 16GB and that Horizon needed about 30gb. But apparently those were not for full history. What is the expected disk requirements so I can spin up a VPS accordingly?

Comment: For a full history archiver node you currently need 234G for the postgresql db and stellar-core history combined (ledger 20945414).

I just finished a full catchup on two machines and it took 15 days to complete each. This is consistent with what I heard from others. @tomer I would love to hear more about how to reduce the time to 2-7 days :)

Comment: PS: Moved on to horizon and observe the exact same problem as you. I am hoping it will go away when my validators stops publishing checkpoints. After 15 days my validator state is "Synced!" but it is still publishing some checkpoints: "Publishing 582 queued checkpoints [20930239-20967551]". I hops Horizon will start ingesting historical data when this is completed.